# Smoothening algorithm to serve ads evenly in a month

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, statistics

Say I have 10 ads that are displayed on a website.

If ad #1 is to be displayed 100K in a given month, how would you go about evenly/smoothly display these ads throughout the day?

I have to take traffic spikes into consideration, so I can't simply divide 30 days by 100K or 3K impressions per day.

Is there a formula for this type of problem domain?

Comment: The thing about the traffic spikes is ambiguous. If the spikes are intra-day, splitting evenly for all day of the month is fine. If the spike is intra-week, you can use an histogram of the anticipated traffic, then change the scale so the count is equal to the total impressions you must have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, for one thing you cannot know how many visits your site will get, so you cannot ensure that each ad will be shown **exactly** X times. For instance, if ad #1 is to be displayed 100K times, and ad #2 is to be displayed 200K times, but you get only 150K visits, then you cannoy possibly satisfy anything. And on the other hand, if you get 600K visits, then every other visit should have no ad. But you have no way to predict this in advance.

Hence, I'd advise the same thing as tskuzzy - pick ads on random, but adjust their probabilities so that they approach the right amount of views. And, of course, track how many times each ad has been shown, and remove it from the rotation once the limit has been reached.

Let's look at an example. Suppose you have two ads. Ad #1 still needs to be shown for 7 more days, and needs to get 70K more views. Ad #2 needs to be shown for 10 more days, and needs 20K more views. So, ad #1 should be shown on average 10K times each day, and ad #2 - 2K times each day. So the probability of ad #1 coming up should be 10/(10+2)=5/6, and the probability of ad #2 should be 2/(10+2)=1/6. Hence for every 12K views you will get on average 10K views of ad #1, and 2K views of ad #2. Which is what you need.

Recalculate these probabilities at the start of each day and only add new ads at the same time. If you add new ads in the middle of the day, it will complicate things. However it will work just as well if you calculate time in seconds, not in days, so you might do that too for a greater accuracy. Just keep an eye on performance if you recalculate everything so often.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the relative proportion of ads and display them with that probability at any given time of the day.

Say you have 3 ads:

```
Ad 1 - 1000 impressions
Ad 2 - 5000 impressions
Ad 3 - 4000 impressions
```

You would display Ad 1 10% of the time, Ad 2 50% of the time, and Ad 3 40% of the time. Every time an ad is displayed, update the # of remaining impressions and probabilities accordingly.

Comment: You'd also need to decrement the counts and update probabilities as ads are served.

Comment: Of course. We don't want to give away free advertising now do we? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for strings like `"ad swapping" +algorithm` or `"ad round-robin"`. Google didn't return anything good for the first search; try duckduckgo.com.
`Vilx-` gave a great response. I'll just add what's missing:

The asker hinted that he's worried about the very real chance that with a very high spike ("slashdot effect") providers run out of ALL rotated ads in a short amount of time. This is probably never contemplated until after it's actually happened, and it sounds like his company isn't big enough to have reached that issue. Today's web-2.0 viral "15-minutes of fame" makes that a very real issue, though.

Because nobody wants to pay up for ads wasted on a spike that brings a "non-diverse audience", there will be non-technical problems that cannot be resolved with just code.

That leads to the only likely response: prepare an extreme service exception clause in ad contracts to either outline a compensation / re-imbursement % policy (**unfair to the poster's ad distributor company**) or stop serving ads altogether just as expected (like certain stocks and sometimes entire stock exchanges completely stop all trading when something is seriously wrong - AOL did just that yesterday). After all, the million ads were all served! You can now open up to new clients! (and lose the old ones). Middle-ground policies would have to be reached, but unbalance is common... after all, we know what happens when you fully consume your site's bandwith --shutdowns and/or rude billing messages that show the leasee isn't getting unfair service beyond the traffic they contracted... capped phone data plans are another example... you either bill extra and lose the customer, or stop providing juice and also lose them. Lose / lose, so someone must give up some contractual strength, and this is up to sales departments and not coders like us.

This must also be simulated to see how the webpages display "empty" ads when you auto-served a million and one ads in a single day for only 1 million planned ads --after all, nobody likes seeing zero ads for the other 29 business days!

It's a tough spot because the content providers (bloggers using the page subsidized by the ad-makers) are ALSO likely to be mad at reaching bandwidth limits imposed by your hosting service... all at the same time as your Ad revenue providers cause some sort of business trouble for your midsize company. This is probably discussed in college e-commerce classes, and isn't something anyone can fix.

Comment: "Because nobody wants to pay up for ads wasted on a spike that brings a "non-diverse audience"" <-- That's simply not true. A lot of Company even prefer their ads to be targeted to a specific audience.

Comment: your getting to philosophical here, looking for a technical response :)